# Yacc: Invalid characters: ' '

Tags: flex-lexer, yacc

I am writing a program using flex/bison to evaluate an arithmetic expression. I can't figure out the mistake in the lex/yacc file. It says ' ' is an invalid character. How to add the spaces in a lex file as a rule so that it isn't considered as invalid?

Lex program

```
%{ 
#include<math.h> 
extern yylval; 
%} 
%%
 
[0-9]+ {yylval=atoi(yytext);return NUM;} 
[+] {return '+';} 
[-] {return '-';} 
[*] {return '*';} 
[/] {return '/';}  
. {return yytext[0];}
\n return 0; 
%%
```

Yacc:

```
%{
#include<stdio.h> 
%}

%token NUM 
%left '-' '+'
%right '*' '/' 
%start S
%%
S   : exp{printf("%d\n",$$);} 
;
exp :   exp '+' exp{$$=$1+$3;} 
    |   exp'-'exp{$$=$1-$3;} 
    |   exp'*'exp{$$=$1*$3;} 
    |   exp'/'exp {if($3==0) exit(0);
else 
$$=$1/$3; 
 }
|NUM 
;
%%
 
#include "lex.yy.c"
void main() 
{ 
printf("Enter the Expr. in terms of integers\n"); 
yyparse(); 
printf("Valid");
}
yywrap(){} 
yyerror() 
{ 
printf("Error\n"); 
}
```

This is the error:

```
arith.y:5.11: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
arith.y:7.15: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
arith.y:10.34: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
arith.y:12.39: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
arith.y:13.37: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
arith.y:14.37: error: invalid characters: ‘ ’
```

Comment: I think you have typographical quotes (`‘ ’`) instead of simple quotes (`'`) in your arith.y file. Also, you should make sure quoted characters are separated from other symbols with a space.

Comment: Is this a compiler error or is it a parsing error? Because when copying your code, it seems to compile properly with no errors.